# Check if a "run-time" multidimensional array key exists

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array. I need a function that checks if a specified key exists.

Let's take this array

```
$config['lib']['template']['engine'] = 'setted';
```

A function should return true when I call it with:

```
checkKey('lib','template','engine');
//> Checks if isset $config['lib']['template']['engine']
```

Note that my array isn't only 3 dimensional. It should be able to check even with only 1 dimension:

```
checkKey('genericSetting');
//> Returns false becase $c['genericSetting'] isn't setted
```

At the moment I am using an awful `eval` code, I would like to hear suggest :)

Comment: Is `$config` guaranteed to be a global variable? And where will `genericSetting` be? Because it doesn't exist in your sample `$config` right now.

Comment: @bolt: yes in your function you can simply do a `global $config;` for what regards `checkKey('genericSetting');` it should return false because as you said there isn't this key in the array

Comment: @yes123: OK. Means when you pass `genericSetting` it checks for `$config['genericSetting']`, right?

Comment: did u see examples given here : http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php

Comment: Just out of interest, what's wrong with `isset($config['lib']['template']['engine'])`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
function checkKey($array) {
  $args = func_get_args();
  for ($i = 1; $i < count($args); $i++) {
    if (!isset($array[$args[$i]]))
       return false;
    $array = &$array[$args[$i]];
  }
  return true;
}
```

Usage:

```
checkKey($config, 'lib', 'template', 'engine');
checkKey($config, 'genericSetting');
```

Comment: Don't use isset. Use array_key_exists. isset===evil.

Comment: @golez: the only difference is how they handle NULL value that's not that bad

Comment: Hey @levu and llnk this function is what I am looking for. But can you guys help me in this if I need to send the array key as string by adding a second parameter and if key exist true then return value else return null value. **Example** checkkey($config , 'lib[template][engine]') and get setted in response.
_thanks in advance_

Answer (score 1):

I created the following two functions to do solve the same problem you are having.

The first function **check** is able to check for one/many keys at once in an array using a dot notation. The **get_value** function allows you to get the value from an array or return another default value if the given key doesn't exist. There are samples at the bottom for basic usage. The code is mostly based on CakePHP's Set::check() function.

```
<?php

function check($array, $paths = null) {
    if (!is_array($paths)) {
        $paths = func_get_args();
        array_shift($paths);
    }

    foreach ($paths as $path) {
        $data = $array;

        if (!is_array($path)) {
            $path = explode('.', $path);
        }

        foreach ($path as $i => $key) {
            if (is_numeric($key) && intval($key) > 0 || $key === '0') {
                $key = intval($key);
            }

            if ($i === count($path) - 1 && !(is_array($data) && array_key_exists($key, $data))) {
                return false;
            }

            if (!is_array($data) || !array_key_exists($key, $data)) {
                return false;
            }

            $data =& $data[$key];
        }       
    }

    return true;
}

function get_value($array, $path, $defaultValue = FALSE) {    
    if (!is_array($path))
        $path = explode('.', $path);

    foreach ($path as $i => $key) {
        if (is_numeric($key) && intval($key) > 0 || $key === '0')
            $key = intval($key);

        if ($i === count($path) - 1) {
            if (is_array($array) && array_key_exists($key, $array))
                return $array[$key];
            else
                break;
        }

        if (!is_array($array) || !array_key_exists($key, $array))
            break;

        $array = & $array[$key];
    }

    return $defaultValue;
}

// Sample usage
$data = array('aaa' => array(
            'bbb' => 'bbb',
            'ccc' => array(
                'ddd' => 'ddd'
            )
        ));

var_dump( check($data, 'aaa.bbb') ); // true
var_dump( check($data, 'aaa.bbb', 'aaa.ccc') ); // true
var_dump( check($data, 'zzz') ); // false
var_dump( check($data, 'aaa.bbb', 'zzz') ); // false

var_dump( get_value($data, 'aaa.bbb', 'default value') ); // "bbb"
var_dump( get_value($data, 'zzz', 'default value') ); // "default value"
```