# Checking if an array key exists

Tags: php, json

I have a multidimensional array produced by **json_decode()**. The json is dynamically generated, that means some keys will be present randomly.

I would like to avoid **Undefined index:** notice, so i encapsulated the calls to the array in a function like this:

```
function exists($value) {
    if (isset($value)) {
        return $value;
    }
}
```

I then call data:

```
$something = exists($json_array['foo']['bar']['baz']);
```

But i still get the **Undefined index: baz** notice. Any suggestions?

Comment: I choose `if(strlen($value) > 0)` because sometimes array isn't set so it just show black but in isset it returns true )

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check if a "run-time" multidimensional array key exists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6080991/check-if-a-run-time-multidimensional-array-key-exists)

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are new to PHP, so I'll give a bit lengthier answer than normal.

```
$something = exists($json_array['foo']['bar']['baz']);
```

This is equivalent to what you wrote:

```
$baz = $json_array['foo']['bar']['baz'];
$something = exists($baz);
```

As you may have noticed, this means that `$json_array['foo']['bar']['baz']` is evaluated before it's passed to `exists()`. This is where the undefined index is coming from.

The correct idiom would be more like this:

```
$something = NULL;
if (isset($json_array['foo']['bar']['baz'])) {
    $something = $json_array['foo']['bar']['baz'];
}
```

The following is also identical to the above lines:

```
$something = isset($json_array['foo']['bar']['baz'])
    ? $json_array['foo']['bar']['baz']
    : NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

You would have to chain the `exists` calls one by one, because you are trying to dereference the array before you send it to the exists function.

See this question for more info: [Check if a "run-time" multidimensional array key exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6080991/check-if-a-run-time-multidimensional-array-key-exists)

Answer (score 0):

`$json_array['foo']['bar']['baz']` fails when you pass it as an argument, before it's passed to `isset()`. That is your problem.