# How to check if JSON index (key) exists?

Tags: php, json, indexing, key, undefined

I have this API that returns this:

> {"response":
>   [{"cid":5122405,"title":"Austin","area":"Estrie","region":"Quebec"},{"cid":5467453,"title":"Austin","region":"Manitoba"}]}

I want to print all *areas*, but as an example above, Austin in Quebec has area value (Estrie), but Austin in Manitoba doesn't.

My code is:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($json_array['response']); ++$i){ 
    echo $json_array['response'][$i]['area'];
```

but the problem is I get this error Notice: **Undefined index: area in...** where area value is not present (like Austin in Manitoba).

How can I check is *area* is present or not?

Comment: `if(isset($json_array['response'][$i]['area']))`

Comment: @Xatoo that might as well be the answer to the Question

Comment: Well in this scenario it could be flagged as a duplicate otherwise

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Checking if an array key exists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22003668/checking-if-an-array-key-exists)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's two basic ways to can deal with this problem.

The simplest is to check the existence of the variable

```
echo array_key_exists('area', $json_array['response'][$i]) ? $json_array['response'][$i]['area'] : null;
```

The other way is to standardise the response from the API so that the `area` key always exists

```
function standardizeApi($values) 
{
    foreach ($values['response'] as $i => $details) {
        if (!array_key_exists('area', $details)) {
            $values['response'][$i]['area'] = null; // default value
        }
    }
    return $values;
}

$json_array = standardizeApi($json_array);
// loop though as normal
```

The second way is better if you have more than one key to check. You can ensure the array contains values, even if the api is missing them.

Edit: Spelling

Answer (score 0):

quick if

```html
for($i = 0; $i < count($json_array['response']); ++$i){ 
     if($json_array['response'][$i]['area']){
echo $json_array['response'][$i]['area'];

};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the json decode as an object and get the item list:

```
$stringJson = '{"response":[{"cid":5122405,"title":"Austin","area":"Estrie","region":"Quebec"},{"cid":5467453,"title":"Austin","region":"Manitoba"}]}';
$jsonObj = json_decode($stringJson);
foreach ($jsonObj->response as $item) {
   echo $item->cid; // 5122405 5467453
}
```